# Dsplaying value from db in jsp dropdown

Tags: jsp, select, drop-down-menu, struts2, struts-tags

I have a form in which i can search with a particular acknowledgement number. It then checks if its present in the db or not. If the value is present in the db then it returns some records from the db and displays in the form. I am using struts 2.

My problem is there are some dropdowns in the form. I am displaying the value from the db in he form using the following struts tag: (suppose fieldOne is a text filed and fieldTwo is a dropdown)

```
<s:textfield name="fieldOne" label="fieldOne" id="fieldOne" value="%{fieldOne}" />

<select name="fieldTwo" id="fieldTwo" value="%{fieldTwo}">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

fieldOne is coming properly. But i am not sure how to display the dropdown value of fieldTwo. If i write  `<s:textfield name="fieldTwo" label="fieldTwo" id="fieldTwo" value="%{fieldTwo}" />`
 it will display the value. But I want to show it in a dropdown list. Ant suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` tag to display the dropdown. If you put a `value` attribute to the tag, the option with that value will be pre-selected.

```
<s:select name="fieldTwo" id="fieldTwo" list="{'Male','Female'}" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select" value="%{fieldTwo}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need arraylist to populate the dropdown from db.something like this,

```
    <s:select key="selectedValue"  id="city" name="city" list="cityList" label="Select City"/>
```

in action class

```
static List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
//create getters and setters
```

in execute method of action class.

```
cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
cityList.add("male");
cityList.add("female");
setCityList(cityList);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to display the value from database in the dropdown. I tried below:

`<s:select key="fieldTwo"  id="fieldTwo" name="fieldTwo" list="cityList" value="%{fieldTwo}" />`

But i am not getting the actual value. its displaying the value of the object like com.test.model@@130aca2.

Comment: try above solution with static list